# Why are some entities NSManagedObjects and some named after their class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios

I've noticed that in my Core Data data model, some entities are (in the top-left panel) have a class of 'NSManagedObject' and some are named after a class (Person, Company etc). There doesn't seem to be any logic in whether the entity has a class of NSManagedObject of Person etc. And my code seems to work ok. So I'm wondering why there is the disparity?

**EDIT**

Thanks for Benedict Cohen for making things a bit clearer. 
This is my current code:

```
Person *per = (Person *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[per setName:@"Steve Jobs"];
```

..This works whether a custom class is explicitly mentioned in the Data Model or not. But I would still need the custom class. Am I doing this wrong? I wonder if I can simplify my code. The custom classes were created by selecting the entities and going to 'New File - Managed Object Class'.. but I think links may have broken when I changed them.

Comment: the logic is: You created it, now you have it. Custom classes are not used unless you have created a custom class.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:` because the return type is `id`, not `NSManagedObject`. When the type is `id` the compiler assumes you know what you're doing and doesn't issue any warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good practice to create a class for each entity, but it is not required. By creating a class for an entity it makes it possible to use properties instead of `setValue:forKey:` eg:

```
person.name = @"Harry Hippy"; //this is good
[person setValue:@"Harry Hippy" forKey:@"naem"]; //this is bad. The compiler won't notice the typo and will result in a run-time error
```

You'll have to create a class as soon as `Person` needs to do more than store data.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question. It looks like I need a custom class because I am casting it to the custom class? .. also, can you give an example of what a managedobject custom class would need to do more than store data..?

Comment: For example you could implement a function that shows a message if you try to save a name with less than 2 characters.